# Java Regular Expressions: How to express a string that can be ANYTHING?

Tags: java, regex

I've been working with an online regular expression tester to develop a Java regular expression.

What I would like is a regular expression that will match a particular pattern at the start of a strong, a particular pattern at the end of a string, and ANYTHING in between in that string.

For example it would file names structured like this

```
^StartOfAFileName_middleOfAFileName_EndOfAFileName.java$
```

The `"_middleOfAFileName_"` can literally be anything.

I tried this something similar to this in the regular expression tester, but it failed:

```
^StartOfAFileName_**\***_EndOfAFileName.java$
```

Any idea what the Java regex equivalent of a `"*"` or any string/any pattern would be?

Comment: Is `StartOfAFileName__EndOfAFileName.java` to be considered valid (i.e., is empty content ok for the middle part)? What about `StartOfAFileName_EndOfAFileName.java` (i.e., if empty content is ok, is it ok to omit one of the underscores)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `.*`.  The `.` is "any character and the `*` is any number of them.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Comment: I tried that.  In the regex tester I am using periods are being taken as literals.  A pattern of .java$   matches ".java", the period isn't interpreted as any character.   I tried  .*  and it didn't work in the regex

Comment: @Steve Irrespective of what your regex tester says, in a regex Java's Pattern class will interpret `.` as any character. It's part of the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @Steve please show your code which can help us point mistake if any.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in code/context:

```
String str = "StartOfAFileName_middleOfAFileName_EndOfAFileName.java";
String pattern = "^StartOfAFileName.*EndOfAFileName.java$";
System.out.println(str.matches(pattern) ? "\nMATCHES" : "\nDOESN'T MATCH");
```